# how to make seo friendly url for dynamic title in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am working on the multiple post site,there will be multiple post, what i need to do that i need dynamic seo friendly url with the post title,  
Suppose i have created the one post like `"sachin tendulkar"` then in yii2 its url should be like `http://domain.com/sachin-tendulkar` how can i do this in url ? Is there anyone who have better solution for this ? 
How can i manage this issue in yii2, if there will be any example then really appreciated. I tried googling but didnt get the any proper solution

Answer (score 2):

Use SluggableBehavior http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-sluggablebehavior.html.

Create new column in a table with your posts and add this code in your ActiveRecord:

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => yii\behaviors\SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'title',
                // 'slugAttribute' => 'slug',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Post's title will create in slug automatically.

After that use this slug in an action method in your Controller to get the right post. For example:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function actionView($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::findOne(['slug'=>$slug]);
        .....
    }
}
```

Also, for pretty url you should set the enablePrettyUrl property in the urlManager section in your config file (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls) and setting rules like that:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    ....
    'rules' => [
         'post/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+>' => 'post/view',
          ....
    ],
]
```